# Кнопка навигации

Tags: html, css

Как сделать кнопку навигации по сайту, или же чтоб кнопка переводила на опреденный элемент страницы?

Answer (score 1):

Использовав якоря http://htmlbook.ru/samhtml/yakorya

Ссылку делаете вида `href="#anchor"`

и добавив к элементу `id="anchor"`

Или вам что-то другое нужно? По вопросу сложно понять что конкретно вы хотите получить. Будет проще если покажите код, и объясните что требуется реализовать в нем.

Answer (score 0):

Возможно, здесь есть всё что вам нужно:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  let scroll_link = $('.scroll');

  scroll_link.click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    let url = $('body').find($(this).attr('href')).offset().top;
    $('html, body').animate({
      scrollTop: url
    }, 700);
    $(this).parent().addClass('active');
    $(this).parent().siblings().removeClass('active');
    return false;
  });
});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  height: 100vh;
}

.jumbotron-fluid {
position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
}

.nav {
  background: #fff;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 50px;
  z-index: 10;
}

.nav-item {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 50px;
  line-height: 50px;
  margin: 0 10px;
}

.nav-item.active .nav-link {
  color: #cb356b;
}

.display {
  color: #fff;
  display: block;
  margin-top: 0px;
  position: sticky;
  top: 50px;
}

.one {
  background: chocolate;
}

.two {
  background: rosybrown;
}

.three {
  background: green;
}

.four {
  background: cornflowerblue;
}

button {
  display: block;
  margin: 30px;
  padding: 30px;
  top: 55px;
}

#elem {
padding-top: 55px;
}
.elem {
  margin: 30px;
  padding: 30px;
  margin-top: 0px;
  position: sticky;
  background-color: red;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container-fluid">
  <ul class="nav fixed-top">
    <li class="nav-item active">
      <a class="nav-link scroll" href="#one">Один</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link scroll" href="#two">Два</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link scroll" href="#three">Три</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link scroll" href="#four">Четыре</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <div class="jumbotron-fluid text-center one" id="one">
    <span class="display">Один<a class="scroll" href="#elem"><button>Кнопка</button></a></span>

  </div>
  <div class="jumbotron-fluid text-center two" id="two">
    <span class="display">Два</span>
    <div id="elem"><div class="elem">Опреденный элемент страницы</div></div>
  </div>
  <div class="jumbotron-fluid text-center three" id="three">
    <span class="display">Три</span>
  </div>
  <div class="jumbotron-fluid text-center four" id="four">
    <span class="display">Четыре</span>
  </div>
</div>
```